# Make text overflow to the left side with CSS

Tags: html, css, text, overflow

I have this main titles that have following CSS properties:

```
text-align:right;
padding-right:30px;
border-right: 3px solid #c7342d;
float:left;
width:300px;
```

Font of the titles is very large and there are long words that go over `300px` in width. This causes some words to overflow, but they overflow to the right into the `padding` & `border` area instead to the left.

**Is there a way to force text to overflow to the left?**

Here are several examples just so that you understand what I'm after:
(second image is how it should look)
[image: Example no.1]

[image: Example no.2]

[image: Example no.3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following CSS rule to your title,

```
direction: rtl;
```

This will make it *right-to-left* and will thus invert the overflow direction.

Comment: Great idea, I completely forgot about rtl. But still, it has problems with punctuation. For examle, exclamation mark is now on the left side of the sentence (I will probably modify my text a little to fit this).

Comment: as Jinx says, this is messes with punctuation... I guess ideally there would be a solution that allowed me to write "MyThing." and have it not mess with the "."